# vimeo embeds start automatically inside hidden div

Tags: javascript, vimeo

I have two vimeo ebmed videos on my page. both are set to autoplay, and are inside a hidden div.

In windows, on all browsers - no problem.

In mac - the two videos start to play automatically as I enter the page...

I'm using fancybox also

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the video at the mac uses HTML5 video and on Windows it uses Flash? A difference between the two is that HMTL5 video/audio will autostart even if the element is hidden.